# jQuery multiselect is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, multi-select

I'm very new to any sort of web related stuff but have been working away for a few weeks on a web project at work. Today though I hit a problem that I couldn't solve. I have been using the multiselect plugin, http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/, for a while without issue.

Today I tried to include the DataTables plugin (https://www.datatables.net/) but after doing so the multiselect function is no longer available. Attached is a simple example showing a minimal example of when things break down when the plugin is included. As it is shown, this code will work and when run will show a dropdown box. However when the uncommented line is included and the DataTable plugin added, the console in Chrome gives the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function(anonymous function)
@ test.php:20i 
@ datatables.min.js:14j.fireWith 
@ datatables.min.js:14n.extend.ready 
@ datatables.min.js:14K 
@ datatables.min.js:14
```

From that it seems like the plugins are in conflict somehow, so I'm not quite sure how to resolve this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.multiselect.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script-->

<?php

    echo "<span id='test'>
        <select multiple='multiple' id='test_dropdown'>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </span>";

?>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test_dropdown").multiselect();
});

</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<?php

    echo "<span id='test'>
        <select multiple='multiple' id='test_dropdown'>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </span>";

?>
```

this code to static output

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with this